# Plone making second http request by itself

Tags: python-requests, plone, plone-5.x

I got a plone 5 project where I work, and my HD just died. I had to reinstall in a new one, which is fine, and everything is working properly, except the fact that, looking at the log, I realized that every time my backend makes a request, it requests twice, once in http, and another in https.

Outside that, the GET type of requests works just fine, but the POST, PUT, DELETE types of request do not. They are built properly and should work, since when I push it to the development env, it works, but not on my localhost, they always receive an error 500.

Looking at the logs of the API I was posting to (Java), it states null pointer exception, but doesn't say where (and the devs didn't want to look either, since it's my problem and not theirs).

Does anyone have a idea on what is happening?

Comment: Do you have a bit more information, some code for example?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of code example i could show. I mean, the server is doing it by itself, on any(literally any) request (im using the requests library).

Comment: You should ask this in our forum, https://community.plone.org. Please see https://plone.org/support on how to best get help with Plone